# how to add a click event to item of KryptonContextMenu?

Tags: krypton-toolkit

Can anyone explain how to add a click event to an item, the documentation is literally lacking EVERYTHING.
Thanks for your concern！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one of two ways:

1. Using code (just like you'd do with any other event):

   ```
   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       kryptonContextMenuItem1.Click += KryptonContextMenuItem1_Click;
   }

   private void KryptonContextMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Do something.
   }
   ```
2. Using the designer. You can't do by double-clicking the item (like what you'd do with a regular `ToolStripMenuItem`) because the item isn't exposed to the designer. So, you'll have to go to the Properties window, select the item from the dropdown, click the Events button ⚡, find the event, and double-click *that*:

   [image: Demo]